# libvirt qemu - VM with X, Host without X. How bring the guests X to a second screen?

Tags: xorg, libvirt

How can I display the X session of a libvirt-qemu VM on a second screen without installing X on the host?

Comment: Physical hypervisor without X?.. hmm that means binding physical vga/hdmi/.. port. Interesting!

Comment: Search for VGA passthrough

Comment: I know VGA passthrough but that is not what I want, I want a simple graphical interface on a physical screen but no dedicated graphics.

Comment: Ok, so maybe an xinit launching a vnc viewer

Comment: Found something with SDL and directfb, i wonder